# Hyperlinks are linking to non-existent HTML file?

Tags: html, css, web, hyperlink

I cannot figure out why my nav bar hyperlinks are trying to link to a document that I don't even have saved on my computer. The href link reads "../KiloArt/about.html" which is the correct hyperlink, however, it keeps actually linking to "file:///C:/Users/Home/Documents/KiloArt/theimpacts.html". The file "theimpact.html" is where i took some of my code from, but have since deleted it from my computer. Any reason why this is? It is happening with some of the other links to, attempting to link to pages that i have since deleted.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't pointing to the website you think you are.  More information is needed.  If you are using html files and have the file open in a text editor and see the `href` is one thing and when you open that file in your browser you see another thing, something is very wrong with your computer.

Comment: Jason- That's exactly what is happening, but what could even be causing this? In theory, it seems impossible.

Comment: Just because you deleted the files that you linked to, doesn't mean the links themselves are also gone. It'll try to link to those file, but when it doesn't find them, it'll just show some error like, file not found.

Comment: Is it possible that the file you're linking to is redirecting you?

Comment: yes, i am being redirected to the wrong file, just getting this error message

Comment: Can you post the html?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>KiloArt</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../KiloArt/assignment4.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../KiloArt/assignment4.js"></script> 
</head>
<h1 class = "title"><p>KiloArt<p></h1>
<table style="width:100%">
 <td class = "nav"><a href= "../KiloArt/visions.html">Visions</a></td>
 <td class = "nav"><a href= "../KiloArt/apparel.html">Apparel</a></td>
 <td class = "nav"><a href= "../KiloArt/about.html">About</a></td>
 <td class = "nav"><a href= "thesolution.html">Xibalba</a></td>
  </tr> 
  </table>

Comment: <pre> <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>KiloArt</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../KiloArt/assignment4.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../KiloArt/assignment4.js"></script> 
</head>
<h1 class = "title"><p>KiloArt<p></h1>
<table style="width:100%">
 <td class = "nav"><a href= "../KiloArt/visions.html">Visions</a></td>
 <td class = "nav"><a href= "../KiloArt/apparel.html">Apparel</a></td>
 <td class = "nav"><a href= "../KiloArt/about.html">About</a></td>
 <td class = "nav"><a href= "thesolution.html">Xibalba</a></td>
  </tr> 
  </table></pre>

Comment: sorry guys, i'm new to stackoverflow and development, my first post isn't goin as planned, unsure of how to get this html properly structured in a comment.

Comment: problem solved, it was linking to some loose file that i thought i had already removed. man, i feel like an idiot, but i could've sworn i checked it 20 times. Appreciate everyone's help, thanks all!

Comment: @DeemStarr OK. But next time, when someone asks you to post HTML, please edit the question and put it in there. In the question at least it can be formatted properly.